# XMLHttpRequest путь

Tags: javascript, xml

Есть javascript файл, лежит в js/script.js в нем следующий код:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        genProducts(xhttp);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", 'products.xml', true);
xhttp.send();
```

JS код вставлен на пару страниц в разных папках, при попытке их загрузить, кидает ошибку:

```
S_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

При загрузке index.html(т.е. где рядом лежит products.xml) всё нормально. Как прописать нормальный путь или есть другие варианты прочитать XML с DOM моделью. Спасибо

Comment: как запускается `index.html`?

Comment: открывается с браузера

Comment: каким образом? просто как файл с диска? какой урл виден в адресной строке браузера?

Comment: ну поднял денвер, и зашёл на сайт. Пытается искать xml в папках где находится html который открываю

Comment: а где на самом деле лежит файл?

Comment: --- главная папка  
  -- products.xml  
  -- index.html <- этот открываю всё норм
  -- папка1  
     -- index.html <- пытается искать файл /папка1/products.xml и ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отсутствии лидирующего слэша в адресе, он расценивается как путь относительно текущего адреса.

Если лидирующий слэш присутствует - адрес вычисляется относительно корня сайта.

Таким образом в качестве решения можно использовать два варианта:

1. относительно текущей страницы (считая что "папка1" лежит в корне сайта, и "products.xml" так же в корне сайта)

   ```
   "../products.xml"
   ```
2. относительно корня сайта (считая что "products.xml" в корне сайта):

   ```
   "/products.xml"
   ```

Comment: спасибо, на хостинге это помогло, при таком варианте при открытии файла без хостинга, то   
  
         script.js:9 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/html/products.xml.        Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.       

нельзя?

Comment: @user_21, именно, вообще запросы xmlhttprequest не должны работать без сервера. В крайнем случае можно попробовать прописать полный путь к файлу, включая протокол `file:///` но скорее всего это тоже не сработает

Comment: Спасибо, а есть другие вариант прочитать xml?

Comment: @user_21, в смысле? можно попробовать использовать xslt, и запускать не index.html, а сразу products.xml

Comment: да просто надо именно по xml :(

Comment: @user_21, не понял комметарий последний

Comment: трансформация не нужна, надо именно по xml пройти

Comment: @user_21, тогда только с использованием сервера. по другому никак

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но метод open настраивает ваше подключение, может имеет смысл его поставить перед самим соединением?

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", 'products.xml', true);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        genProducts(xhttp);
    }
};
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Неа, `onreadystatechange` - это событие, которое произойдёт только после `xhttp.send()`, так что пусть ставит где хочет, не критично.